# How to get Android.Content.Context object in Android head

Tags: android, uno-platform

I'm working on integrating an java binding project, and I need to pass an Android.Content.Context object to the method, how do I get that in Uno?

Comment: why you not used static??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the current Android `Context` within an Uno app you can use the `Uno.UI.ContextHelper.Current` property.

Simple example:

```cs
#if __ANDROID__
    public partial class CustomNativeScrollView : Android.Widget.ScrollView
    {
        public CustomNativeScrollView() : base(Uno.UI.ContextHelper.Current)
        {

        }

    ...
```